# What is this pattern/algo called? Getting a random order of subscribers to an event that only one can react to at a time

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I've got a problem where I have an event publisher in c# serving up a **global resource to a bunch of subscribers**. The resource is a rival good, so it is possible that there won't be enough of it for all the consumers.

The model to imagine is a shipment of ingredients arriving at a market. A number of chefs are waiting for each ingredient and must decide whether to buy some of each as each is served up. The chefs agree that everyone should have a shot at each ingredient, and they don't want a race for each item, so they decide some kind of priority system should exist.

1) Is there a name for this kind of scenario?

2) **What is a good way to implement this in a fair way, so each subscriber has an equal chance of getting the ingredient?** Keep in mind that the decision on whether to ask for the resource is dependent on the subscriber.

3) Note that priority does not necessitate fixed priority. If you had a dice roll before each event, you could create an order each time. You could also precalculate this. Are there any drawbacks to such a solution?

Anyway, this isn't a homework question. Just wondering if someone has seen this or is able to cast a common solution into a form that solves this.

Comment: This reminds me of the loot system in World of Warcraft. :-D

Comment: That's not a bad analogy either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is there a name for this kind of scenario?

Yes, it is called [Round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin) (if I got it correctly)

> 2) What is a good way to implement this in a fair way, so each subscriber has an equal chance of getting the ingredient?

The more complex the system, the easier you should make a solution, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) works really well here. Implement a round-robin algorithm.

> 3) Note that priority does not necessitate fixed priority. If you had a dice roll before each event, you could create an order each time. You could also recalculate this. Are there any drawbacks to such a solution?

This problem has been around for many years in large scalable systems and networking (for example see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/q/101053/82856)). People tried many things, but unless you *really know* what you doing, use a simple one-shot-each-in-a-round strategy.

Round robin is not perfect and definitely has its own drawbacks, but it is also the easiest solution.

Comment: Just to clarify the example, people use DNS tables to load balance their servers? IE multiple routes into a system are load balanced by changing the public address book? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Carlos I am not too sure about the internal details of the DNS, but the idea is: I have *N* servers in a rotation and one load balancer (LB). Servers are stateless and serve exactly the same content to everybody. Users initially make a request to the LB. LB in a round-robin fashion redirects requests to one of the *N* servers. Thus load is evenly distributed amongsts *N* servers.

Comment: More like the router that handles incoming requests to a load-balanced cluster uses a heuristic to determine which server gets the request. Round-robin will simply alternate requests between servers. More advanced heuristics can be weighted to give more traffic to a more powerful server, can keep a client table and send multiple subsequent requests from the same client to the same server (balancing it by sending more requests from new clients to the other one), can monitor server heartbeats and redistribute traffic if a server goes down, etc.

Comment: Ah yes, the internal DNS of the domain owner can do it without changing the public tables.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a draft system of sorts. In some predetermined order, all subscribers are given a right of acceptance or refusal of the resource until the resource is fully leveraged. The trick is how to determine that order.

If this were my project, I think I'd start simple. Start with the first subscriber who subscribed, and proceed through the list in that order until the resource is fully leveraged. Then, as additional resources become available, the first subscriber who did not get to choose (because you ran out of resource) gets right of first refusal, and it continues from there. When you reach the end, cycle back around to the start. This is a good model to use when there are a lot of batches of resource, just not *quite* enough of each to go around. The chef's ingredient model would work well with this system; the first chef who shows up that day gets first pick, and so on around the kitchen, and if a chef gets left out, no worries, he'll get a shot at the next batch.

Another possible method is order-independent. Ask all subscribers whether they want a particular resource. If there are more who want it than there are available resources, put all subscribers' names into a hat and choose X of them; they get the resource. The ones who do not get the resource keep their names in that hat, thus giving them an extra chance to get the next resource. This is the better model to use when batches of resources are small and most or all are highly desirable, to avoid the last subscriber having to wait forever to get the chance at something good. The WoW loot system probably works somewhat like this (with the simplification that all party members "opt-in" for each item; I don't play WoW so I've never seen the loot system work).

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the resource may or may not be leveraged. For instance, nobody in their right mind will ever pick up celery for their recipe. A draft is not a bad analogy either, but suppose you don't want priority to depend on previous performance.

Comment: Hey, celery can be good when prepared right (you have to "de-string" it before slicing it up). Works well in a lot of soups and stuffings. Anyway, that's easy to account for; in the first model (which is the one you commented on) if you come back around to the first subscriber you asked and have not fully leveraged the resource, stop asking.

Answer (score 1):

1> I am not sure if there is a name for this scenario

2> Fair is very subjective. you need to have an optimization criteria to get an optimal solution. You said each subscriber has an equal chance of getting the ingredient. Then you simply need a uniform random variable to decide which one should get it.

But you also said a chef may not want a particular ingredient. So only those chefs who want the current ingredient have to taken into account. So you need to have a weighted distribution that takes into account the fairness between all chefs who want the current ingredient.

This can be done as follows

Assume there are X chefs

All chefs start at zero points.

Everytime a chef gets a resource he gets X points.
All chefs who don't get a resource get -1 points. 
So higher the points you have more the resources you have taken in recent history.
Ideally the resource should be given to the person with the least points.

When you have multiple people on least points, simply choose one using a random uniform distribution.
This would be fair in some sense.

Another option would be to still allow all chefs to get the the resource but use a distribution that is now calculated from the sum of points that the chefs who want the resource. This makes it random with a distribution decided by the chefs who want the resource and their current history in getting resources.